# Progress Bar does not work

Tags: android

Progress Bar does not work, it appears and disappears immediately
I want to progress bar is work all the time until a request is made, it works only for a moment.Explain to me , what it can be connected , I'm confused now!

***Code***

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressBar loading;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        VKRequest request = VKApi.audio().get();
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                list_music = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                URLlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < list_music.size(); i++) {
                    list.add(list_music.get(i).title + " - " + list_music.get(i).artist);
                    URLlist.add(list_music.get(i).url);
                }
                array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(VkMusicAct.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
                listView.setAdapter(array);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
                Toast toastError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastError.show();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPostExecute(Void f) {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onProgressUpdate` to dismiss the dialog. `Override` `onProgressUpdate` in your class as:

```
@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
               loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

and in your `doInBackground()` use it as:

```
  @Override
  public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
  super.onComplete(response);
  list_music = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
  list = new ArrayList<String>();
  URLlist = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (int i = 0; i < list_music.size(); i++) {
        list.add(list_music.get(i).title + " - " + list_music.get(i).artist);
      URLlist.add(list_music.get(i).url);
     }
                array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(VkMusicAct.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
                listView.setAdapter(array);
                publishProgress();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

add your progress bar inside  `onComplete()` method.

see below.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressBar loading;
    Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        activity = (Activity) loading.getContext();
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        VKRequest request = VKApi.audio().get();
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                list_music = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                URLlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < list_music.size(); i++) {
                    list.add(list_music.get(i).title + " - " + list_music.get(i).artist);
                    URLlist.add(list_music.get(i).url);
                }
                array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(VkMusicAct.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
                listView.setAdapter(array);
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void run() {
                                               loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                           }
                                       }
                        }

                @Override
                public void onError(VKError error) {
                    super.onError(error);
                    Toast toastError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toastError.show();
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected  void onPostExecute(Void f) {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
```